# cannot convert varchar to float in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

These are my 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dailyRate](
[SYMBOL] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SERIES] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OPENPRICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[HIGHPRICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LOWPRICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CLOSEPRICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTPRICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PREVCLOSE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTTRDQTY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTTRDVAL] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TIMESTAMPDAY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTALTRADES] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ISIN] [varchar](50) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cmpDailyRate](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SYMBOL] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SERIES] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OPENPRICE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[HIGHPRICE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[LOWPRICE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[CLOSEPRICE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[LASTPRICE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[PREVCLOSE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[TOTTRDQTY] [bigint] NULL,
[TOTTRDVAL] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[TIMESTAMPDAY] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[TOTALTRADES] [bigint] NULL,
[ISIN] [varchar](50) NULL,
[M_Avg] [decimal](18, 4) NULL
)
```

this is my insert query to fetch data from table to another with casting

Collapse | Copy Code

```
INSERT into [Stock].[dbo].[cmpDailyRate]
SELECT [SYMBOL],[SERIES],Str([OPENPRICE], 18,4),Str([HIGHPRICE],18,4),
Str([LOWPRICE],18,4),Str([CLOSEPRICE],18,4),Str([LASTPRICE],18,4),Str([PREVCLOSE],18,4),convert(bigint,[TOTTRDQTY]),Str([TOTTRDVAL],18,4),
convert(date, [TIMESTAMPDAY], 105),convert(bigint,[TOTALTRADES]),[ISIN],null
FROM [Stock].[dbo].[DailyRate]
```

This query runs perfectly in SQL Server 2005, but it's causing errors in SQL Server 2008 (above query run also in SQL Server 2008 when installed; error arise in last few days)

Error :

> *Error cannot convert varchar to float*

What to do?

Comment: Check your data for invalid values

Comment: You don't have a WHERE filter in your example, but I'm curious if you do in your code. If you do, or if DailyRate gets truncated and refilled, you may get the error seemingly randomly if you're getting invalid values in your data. The case statement below is probably the safer approach.

Answer (score 1):

One of your rows contains invalid data in the columns you are doing the float conversion (Str) on.  Use the following strategy to work out which:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dailyRate]
WHERE IsNumeric([OPENPRICE]) = 0
OR IsNumeric([HIGHPRICE]) = 0
```

etc etc.

Comment: I did suggest a AND instead of OR

Comment: @Praveen : An AND would only help if multiple values were incorrect on the same row. The original query will fail if ANY column contains an incorrect value.

Comment: where and isnumeric(...) are not sufficient - sql may (and often does) convert values before applying where condition. case isnumeric(...) then ... else ... end will do the trick.

Comment: @Arvo : In the OP's example. How could SQL auto convert a value to a float and return IsNumeric() = 1 for a value that isn't a valid? What would the result be?

Comment: Sorry, I misread something (I somehow thought about conversion without errors). For just checking invalid values isnumeric() is sufficient of course.

Comment: Except of course that there are values for which `ISNUMERIC()` will return 1 but that which cannot be converted to `float`.

Comment: An example of @Damien_The_Unbeliever's point: `print isnumeric('$1') ; print cast('$1' as float)` results in `1 \n Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 \n Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to filter out data, a CASE statement might work better for you.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN IsNumeric([OPENPRICE]) = 1 THEN [OPENPRICE]
        ELSE NULL -- or 0 or whatever
       END AS OPENPRICE,
       CASE 
        WHEN IsNumeric([HIGHPRICE]) = 1 THEN [HIGHPRICE]
        ELSE NULL -- or 0 or whatever
       END AS [HIGHPRICE]
FROM [dailyRate]
```